# dismissing a UIViewController view and releasing memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

So I have a UIViewController that I am presenting it's view through a delegate, the code is:

```
[self.delegate fullStrViewController: self addFullScreenSubview:fullSize];
```

where fullSize here is the UIViewController I am presenting. Inside fullSize I have a dimiss method which basically remove's the view from the superview. The question is where do I actually call release on fullSize? If I did it after the call to the delegate above, when I call dismiss it will cause an error because the UIViewController has been released. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Any subclass of `UIView` always retains its subviews. Therefore it is safe to call `release` on a `UIView` after adding it as a `subview` to another `UIView`. However, the parent will call `release` on the child when it is sent `dealloc`, so this assumes you only want to child to persist for the life of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

a `UIView` subclass retains a view when you insert it into the view hierarchy.
It will balance that retain by releasing it when your view removes itself from the hierarchy.

If you have no other references to your object at that point it will be dealloced.

Start using ARC and you don't really have to worry about these things.